# Most optimal order (of joins) for left join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

I have 3 tables  Table1 (with 1020690 records), Table2(with 289425 records), Table 3(with 83692 records).I have something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1 /* OK fine select * is bad when not all columns are needed, this is just an example*/
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.id=T3.id
```

and a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.id=T3.id
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
```

The query plan shows me that it uses 2 Merge Join for both the joins. For the first query, the first merge is with T1 and T2 and then with T3. For the second query, the first merge is with T1 and T3 and then with T2.

Both these queries take about the same time(40 seconds approx.) or sometimes Query1 takes couple of seconds longer.

So my question is, does the join order matter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The join order for a simple query like this should not matter.  If there's a way to reorder the joins to improve performance, that's the job of the query optimizer.

In theory, you shouldn't worry about it -- that's the point of SQL. Trying to outthink the query optimizer is generally not going to give better results.  Especially in MS SQL Server, which has a very good query optimizer.

I wouldn't expect this query to take 40 seconds.  You might not have the right indexes defined.  You should use tools like [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) or [SQL Server Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494.aspx) to see if it can recommend any new indexes.

Answer (score 2):

The query optimizer will use a combination of the constraints, indexes, and statistics collected on the table to build an execution plan. In most cases this works well. However, I do occasionally encounter scenarios where the execution plan is chosen poorly. Often times tweaking the query can effectively coerce the optimizer into a choosing a better plan. I can offer no general rules for doing this though. When all else fails you could resort to the `FORCE ORDER` [query hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx).

And yes, the join order can have a significant impact on execution time of your query. The idea is that by joining the tables that yield the smallest results first will cause the next join to be computed more quickly. **Edit:** It is important to note, however, that in the abscense of `FORCE ORDER` and in all other things being equal the order you specify in the query may have no correlation with the way the optimizer builds the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

In general, SQL Server is smart enough to pick out the best way to join and it will not only use the order you wrote in the query. That said, I find it easier to understand a complex query if all the inner joins are first and then the left joins.